# Unexpected behaviour with DiscreteUniform in pymc when shifting interval

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc

I am trying to simulate 100 tossing of a dice, where my *data* is the sum of all the tosses (kind of a Maximum Entropy principle of Jaynes' Brandeis dice). This was my first attempt to later approach a loaded dice.

I am using pymc 2.3

If I set the dice values from 1 to 6 with `DiscreteUniform('dice', 1, 6, size=N)` and set a sum value equal to the average sum value 100*3.5=350, then I get uniform posterior distribution, as expected.

But if I set the dice values from 0 to 5 and the sum equal to 100*2.5=250, the distribution is not uniform. The 0 value is much less sampled! As I am just shifting the values 1 unit, I expected the same result. Any idea why are they different? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

This is the full code:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
shifts = (0, -1)
for shift in shifts:
    obs_mean = 3.5+shift
    obs_total = int(N*obs_mean)
    sigma = 0.01*N
    dice = pm.DiscreteUniform('dice', 1+shift, 6+shift, size=N)

    @pm.deterministic
    def calc_total(d=dice):
        return np.sum(d)

    total = pm.Normal('total', mu=calc_total, tau=1./sigma, observed=True, value=obs_total)

    # package the full model in a dictionary
    model1 = dict(dice=dice, calc_total=calc_total, total=total)

    # run the basic MCMC:
    S = pm.MCMC(model1)
    S.sample(iter=100000, burn=10000)

    dice_trace = S.trace('dice')[:]-shift
    plt.hist(dice_trace.flat, bins=(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5), normed=True, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

**EDIT**: Based on the comments, I've made a simpler model: two uniform distributions, one created from 1 to 6, the other from 0 to 5 and then a deterministic function `dice2` that adds 1 to it, so that the prior `dice2` is the same in both models, and the likelihood depends only on `dice2`, however their posterior distributions are different.

Another interesting case is when shift is set to -7, which results in just inverting the sign of the dice, but results in different posteriors.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
shifts = (0, -1)
for shift in shifts:
    obs_mean = 3.5
    obs_total = int(N*obs_mean)
    sigma = 0.01*N
    dice = pm.DiscreteUniform('dice', 1+shift, 6+shift, size=N)

    @pm.deterministic
    def dice2(d=dice):
        return d-shift

    @pm.deterministic
    def calc_total(d=dice2):
        return np.sum(d)

    total = pm.Normal('total', mu=calc_total, tau=1./sigma, observed=True, value=obs_total)

    # package the full model in a dictionary
    model1 = dict(dice=dice, dice2=dice2, calc_total=calc_total, total=total)

    # run the basic MCMC:
    S = pm.MCMC(model1)
    S.sample(iter=100000, burn=10000)

    dice_trace = S.trace('dice2')[:]
    plt.hist(dice_trace.flat, bins=(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5), normed=True, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with the sampling steps in version 2.3.6 of PyMC. It worked as expected in version 2.3.2. I discussed the issue with Chris Fonnesbeck in [github](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/82) and he corrected it in a developmental version of PyMC. In the future, check which version you have and how it behaves.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear why you would necessarily expect a uniform distribution. The discrete uniform is just your prior. All the model has for information is the sum of 350 for `shift=0` and 250 for `shift=-1`, and will generate parameter estimates with this expectation. When I run the model under each shift value and look at the traces, I get the following distribution for `shift=0` (just looking at the summary by unique values):

```
>>> pd.Series(shift_0.flat).value_counts()

2    1526136
4    1526011
3    1511494
5    1503698
6    1471922
1    1460739
```

which corresponds to an expectation of:

```
>>> pd.Series(shift_0.flat).mean() * 100

350.02311111111112
```

And for `shift=-1`

```
>>> pd.Series(shift_1.flat).value_counts()

1    1894489
2    1724072
3    1577420
4    1457896
5    1320425
0    1025698
dtype: int64


>>> pd.Series(shift_1.flat).mean() * 100

250.08703333333332
```

so, the model appears to be behaving as I would expect.

Comment: Well said. I'll add one piece of intuition as to why the shift changes the distribution: with shift=0, the contribution of the highest roll is equal to the contribution of six of the lowest rolls (6/1=6); with shift=-1, no number of lowest rolls will equal one of the highest rolls (5/0=inf) so intuitively I would expect applying such a shift to change the results.

Comment: I see your point. I still find it puzzling that for shift=0 the results agree with what one would get applying MaxEnt principle. They also agree with MaxEnt if obs_mean is shifted to 4.5. However, the MaxEnt results do not depend on the shift! A uniform distribution is also obtained for the dice with shift=-1. And when the mean is changed to 3.5 (4.5-1), the same reweighting is obtained. So I find it hard to understand that the Bayesian results depend on the values of the dice whereas the MaxEnt don't...

Comment: Chris, But then, if I want a more flexible prior and want to start with something like:
`dice2 = pm.Categorical('dice2', p=np.ones(6)/6) #From 0 to 5`
How can I make it agree with a uniform distribution from 1 to 6?

Comment: Is here a reason you are fixing the likelihood variance to a constant? It related as unknown. Or at least the expected variance of the sum of uniform random variables if you want to assume that.

Comment: Also, do you have the original reference for this? Its not clear why identical results are expected, based on what is coded above.

Comment: I've checked and both codes give different results when using python2 (and pymc 2.3.2) and python3 (and pymc 2.3.4). In the former, the same distribution is obtained with and without shift. So I'm sorry but I think there is a bug in PyMC.